# java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider textsecure for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am new to Android and working on an existing app.I have described the situation below

In my Manifest file I have 3 providers given below:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <provider android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.providers.PartProvider"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true"
          android:exported="false"
          android:authorities="org.mpo.app.provider.prepare" />

    <provider android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.providers.MmsBodyProvider"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true"
          android:exported="false"
          android:authorities="org.mpo.app.provider.prepare.mms" />
```

And in the build.gradle file version details given is like below:

```
    compileSdkVersion 26

    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'

    minSdkVersion 19

    targetSdkVersion 26
```

Everything was working fine on targetSdkVersion: 25, but I need to upgrade it to 26 because of play-store recent rules change.Whenever I tried to run my application it crashes (in Version 26).

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
           Process: org.mpo.app.prepare, PID: 20164
           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application org.mpo.app.prepare.ApplicationContext: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider textsecure for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5955)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1726)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6733)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
            Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider textsecure for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1943)
               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1889)
               at android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:801)
               at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:2046)
               at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:1997)
               at android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:1967)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.database.IdentityDatabase.deleteIdentityRow(IdentityDatabase.java:316)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.database.IdentityDatabase.<init>(IdentityDatabase.java:197)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.database.DatabaseFactory.<init>(DatabaseFactory.java:185)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.database.DatabaseFactory.getInstance(DatabaseFactory.java:108)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.database.DatabaseFactory.getSmsDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:123)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.service.ExpiringMessageManager.<init>(ExpiringMessageManager.java:29)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.ApplicationContext.initializeExpiringMessageManager(ApplicationContext.java:159)
               at org.mpo.app.prepare.ApplicationContext.onCreate(ApplicationContext.java:88)
               at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5952)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1726) 
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206) 
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6733) 
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:845)
```

I searched everywhere and found that there are some problems with contentProvider and Valid AUTHORITY. But not able to understand what exactly should I do?

Really struggling. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="org.mpo.app.prepare">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.amulyakhare.textdrawable,com.astuetz.pagerslidingtabstrip,pl.tajchert.waitingdots,com.h6ah4i.android.multiselectlistpreferencecompat,android.support.v13,com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview,com.tomergoldst.tooltips"/>

    <permission android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ACCESS_SECRETS"
                android:label="Access to TextSecure Secrets"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.portrait" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ACCESS_SECRETS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH"
                     tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RAISED_THREAD_PRIORITY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS"/>

    <permission android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ApplicationContext"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                 android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon_circle_new"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:supportsRtl="true"
                 tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
                 android:allowBackup="false"
                 android:theme="@style/TextSecure.LightTheme"
                 android:largeHeap="true">

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>


    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD18HQmaH7jV-IK1U-bNCqbmLQTbsfCinY"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.mms.TextSecureGlideModule"
               android:value="GlideModule" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
               android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.WebRtcCallActivity"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|fontScale"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.CountrySelectionActivity"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ImportExportActivity"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.preferences.MmsPreferencesActivity"
               android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationListActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:launchMode="singleTask"
          android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
          android:exported="true" />

    <activity-alias android:name=".RoutingActivity"
                    android:targetActivity="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationListActivity"
                    android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.minimode.icon.portrait.normal"
            android:resource="@drawable/icon" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.minimode.icon.landscape.normal"
            android:resource="@drawable/icon" />

    </activity-alias>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationListArchiveActivity"
              android:label="@string/AndroidManifest_archived_conversations"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
              android:parentActivityName="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationListActivity">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationListActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationActivity"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
              android:parentActivityName="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationListActivity">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="org.mpo.app.prepare.ConversationListActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.MessageDetailsActivity"
              android:label="@string/AndroidManifest__message_details"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.GroupCreateActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
          android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.DatabaseMigrationActivity"
              android:theme="@style/NoAnimation.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.NewConversationActivity"
              android:theme="@style/TextSecure.LightNoActionBar"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.VerifyIdentityActivity"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ApplicationPreferencesActivity"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.RegistrationActivity"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.RegistrationProgressActivity"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.SmsSendtoActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.mpo.app.prepare.contact" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.webrtc.VoiceCallShare"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              android:theme="@style/NoAnimation.Theme.BlackScreen"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.org.mpo.app.prepare.call" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.RecipientPreferenceActivity"
              android:theme="@style/TextSecure.LightNoActionBar"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.BlockedContactsActivity"
              android:theme="@style/TextSecure.LightTheme"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.scribbles.StickerSelectActivity"
              android:theme="@style/TextSecure.LightTheme"
              android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"/>

    <activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity" />

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.WebRtcCallService"/>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.ApplicationMigrationService"/>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.KeyCachingService"/>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.RegistrationService"/>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.MessageRetrievalService"/>

    <service android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.QuickResponseService"
             android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
             android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.AccountAuthenticatorService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
    </service>

    <service android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.ContactsSyncAdapterService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE" android:resource="@xml/contactsformat" />
    </service>

    <service android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.DirectShareService"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CHOOSER_TARGET_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.chooser.ChooserTargetService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.SmsListener"
              android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true">
             <intent-filter android:priority="1001">
                 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER"/>
             </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.SmsDeliveryListener"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.services.MESSAGE_SENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.MmsListener"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true"
              android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
             <intent-filter android:priority="1001">
                 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED"/>
                 <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER"/>
                 <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
             </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.MarkReadReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.CLEAR"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.RemoteReplyReceiver"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.WEAR_REPLY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.AndroidAutoHeardReceiver"
              android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.ANDROID_AUTO_HEARD"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.AndroidAutoReplyReceiver"
              android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.ANDROID_AUTO_REPLY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <provider android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.providers.PartProvider"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true"
              android:exported="false"
              android:authorities="org.mpo.app.provider.prepare" />

    <provider android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.providers.MmsBodyProvider"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true"
              android:exported="false"
              android:authorities="org.mpo.app.provider.prepare.mms" />

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.RegistrationNotifier"
              android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.REGISTRATION_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.DirectoryRefreshListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.RotateSignedPreKeyListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.PersistentConnectionBootListener">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.MessageNotifier$ReminderReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.MessageNotifier.REMINDER_ACTION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.notifications.DeleteNotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.DELETE_NOTIFICATION"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.ExperienceUpgradeActivity$AppUpgradeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="org.mpo.app.prepare.service.PanicResponderListener"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="info.guardianproject.panic.action.TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <uses-library android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" android:required="false"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: please share full manifest file

Comment: Hello @Radesh    I have updated the full manifest file. Please have a look.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?